# worklight.property and worklight.plist in nativeResources folder not update in the Native Project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have added the worklight.plist in nativeResource folder with my cloud server details. While building the environment it still gets my localhost development server details, not update from nativeResources folder. Same issue with android, copied wlclient.property file to nativeResources->assets->wlclient.property.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK these two files are not files you can overwrite using the nativeResources folder.

Use the Build Settings and Remote Target wizard to build your application with connection properties to another Worklight Server.

Comment: Hi Adar, Thanks for the response, Using Build Target Wizard is fine for Studio. Actually i am building the environment using Ant Task. In this case how i will set the remote server details to the work light.plist. And i am using the build script to build my .ipa and .apk. So my developers are not manually build using respective IDE. Please let me know any other solution for the same.

Comment: Hi Adar, Please let me know this property in Ant Task will help me to build for the remote server. <property name="wl.server" value="https://mlwls1.azure.net:81/worklight/${project.name}/" />